# How to get QuickBlox server time from QBChatMessage?

Tags: ios, quickblox

When we got a message in delegate:

`- (void)chatDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message`

How we can know what's the UTC time for this message? I'm facing issue with user device date and time. So I've to use server time. Is there a way to get it from `QBChatMessage` object.

P.S. I'm already using date field of `QBChatMessage` class but I want server time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QBChatMessage *message = [QBChatMessage message];
...
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
params[@"date_sent"] = @((int)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
...
[message setCustomParameters:params];
```

More deatils are given in quickblox docs...
http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat

Answer (score 0):

You can get time from above code

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSTimeZone *outputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

[df setTimeZone:outputTimeZone];

NSString *strChatTime = [df stringFromDate:message.datetime];

df = nil
```